# Определить на сайте, когда пользователь дошел до низа страницы

Tags: html, jquery

Когда я пишу этот код, то он у меня он работает наоборот. "Buttom reached" высвечивается когда я дохожу до топа страницы.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
            {
                  alert("bottom reached!");   
            }  
        });
```

Comment: Buttocks reached...)))

Answer (score 1):

Скобки нужны вокруг суммирования.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) == $(document).height())
    {
      alert("bottom reached!");   
    }  
});
```